# i want to display googleadmob's interstitialad in flutter, but i can't display it after loading

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-platform, admob, riverpod

I want to display Google AdMob's InterstitialAd using Riverpod's AsyncNotifier with the code below, but when it is first referenced, only loading is performed and InterstitialAd cannot be displayed and ends. The second reference displays without problems. How can I load the InterstitialAd and display it without ending it?

```dart
// Dart imports:
import 'dart:async';

// Package imports:
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';

// Project imports:
import './interstitial_ad_state.dart';
import '../repository/ad_unit_id.dart';

final interstitialAdProvider =
    AsyncNotifierProvider<InterstitialAdNotifier, InterstitialAdState>(
  () {
    return InterstitialAdNotifier();
  },
);

class InterstitialAdNotifier extends AsyncNotifier<InterstitialAdState> {
  @override
  FutureOr<InterstitialAdState> build() async {
    return await loadInterstitial();
  }

  InterstitialAd? interstitialAd;

  Future<void> showInterstitialAd() async {
    await state.value!.interstitialAd!.show();
  }

  Future<InterstitialAdState> loadInterstitial() async {
    state = const AsyncValue.loading();
    await InterstitialAd.load(
      adUnitId: interstitialAdUnitId,
      request: const AdRequest(),
      adLoadCallback: InterstitialAdLoadCallback(
        onAdLoaded: (InterstitialAd ad) {
          interstitialAd = _settingFullScreen(ad: ad);
          state = AsyncValue.data(
            InterstitialAdState(interstitialAd: interstitialAd),
          );
        },
        onAdFailedToLoad: (LoadAdError error) {
          state = AsyncValue.error(error, StackTrace.current);
        },
      ),
    );
    return InterstitialAdState(interstitialAd: interstitialAd);
  }

  InterstitialAd _settingFullScreen({required InterstitialAd ad}) {
    ad.fullScreenContentCallback = FullScreenContentCallback(
      onAdShowedFullScreenContent: (ad) {
        loadInterstitial();
      },
      onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: (ad, error) {
        state = AsyncValue.error(error, StackTrace.current);
        ad.dispose();
        loadInterstitial();
      },
      onAdDismissedFullScreenContent: (ad) {
        ad.dispose();
      },
    );
    return ad;
  }
}
```

```dart
// Flutter imports:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

// Package imports:
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

// Project imports:
import '/provider/interstitial_ad_notifier.dart';

class InterstitialAdService {
  void showInterstitialAd({required WidgetRef ref}) {
    ref.watch(interstitialAdProvider).when(
          loading: () => const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
          error: (error, _) => Center(child: Text('Error: $error')),
          data: (data) {
            ref.read(interstitialAdProvider.notifier).showInterstitialAd();
          },
        );
  }
}
```